# What is a run on the pound?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy

From the news today, it mentions that Jeremy Corbyn and the Labour Party is preparing to deal with a run on the pound.

What is a run on the pound? Why is it making news headlines?

Why does Jeremy Corbyn plan for this eventuality happening?

The article says that it's where investors sell sterling en masse, but what can the Labour Government do in that situation?

Comment: Could you link to the news piece? Perhaps it was meant to be that Jeremy Corbyn winning the elections would result in investors becoming afraid and selling their pound valued assets, leading to the (unintended) devaluation. "Analysis" like these and other doom predictions in the case the opposite party wins are far from unusual.

Comment: @George You're slightly misunderstanding 'plan for' here. It's 'predict a response to', not 'prepare to carry out' http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-politics-41404494/jeremy-corbyn-it-s-right-to-look-at-all-scenarios

Comment: His policies are likely to lead to a capital outflow. That could cause the pound to dramatically devalue. He want policies that will ameliorate the ill-effects that will occur

Comment: The original question was based on a misconception, but the answers addressed that. Now the question does not fit the answers anymore. Can someone please revert?

Comment: @CarstenS If you have an issue with the answers, edit them. Don't edit baseless insinuations back into what is now a hot question.

Comment: Apologies for any misconceptions, like one of the answers said I just had a quick skim on the first result on Google, which implied that Jeremy Corbyn said it was right to plan for one so I added two and two and got seven!

Answer (score 24):

A "run on the pound" occurs when financial traders believe that it is not in their interest to own "pounds", but an alternative like dollars or euros, or even gold, is a better currency to own. They will then try to sell pounds, and buy the other currencies.  In order to sell quickly they reduce the price at which they are selling pounds. As this happens we say that he value of the pound has dropped. Other investors seeing this drop in price may then try to sell off their pounds very quickly, cutting the price a lot. If everyone is trying to sell, then the value of the pound can drop rapidly against other currencies.

This has several consequences. It means that it costs more for a British company to buy things from abroad. The price of imported goods and raw materials goes up. This makes things more expensive. It makes it more costly to travel abroad. On the other hand, if you are making something in Britain and selling it abroad, it makes that thing cheaper, so it makes exporting more profitable, it also makes it cheaper for tourists to visit the UK. It would add to the costs of the government and lead to higher taxes, inflation and slower growth.

There was a run on the pound after the vote to leave the EU, there was also a run on the pound when it was [forced to leave the ERM in 1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Wednesday)

Generally a run on the pound is a *bad thing* it destabilises international markets that depend on predictable prices. There is a concern that the level of government borrowing implied by the Labour party's policies would cause financial traders to sell pounds in large enough amounts to cause a run, and this would be damaging to the UK economy.

As such the shadow chancellor mentioned in a meeting that he was engaged in planning for this event, even though he said it was unlikely. The fact he mentioned this possibility surprised many journalists, as predicting a run on the pound can be a self-fulfilling prophesy.

So a run on the pound is not something that the Labour party planning to have. Instead the Labour party is planning its defensive strategy if a damaging run on the pound occurs.

Comment: To add to this answer, trading in forex is usually done with (monstrous) leverage. That is, you borrow many times the money you've got in the game to multiply your gains (or losses). This makes it even trickier to defend against runs. Think of it as a dam that is collapsing, with speculators bringing in giant pumps near the breach to force the water out even faster.

Comment: Without knowing the economic terminology, that sounds more like a "run from the pound", and a run on the pound would be in the other direction?

Comment: It is derived from "a run on the bank", though I have no idea where that expression comes from.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Speculators who risk *their own money* are good for an economy, since the only way they can profit is through buying high and selling low, which has the effect of stabilizing prices.  Speculators who buy high and sell low destabilize markets, but if they're using their own money they won't be in those markets for very long.  What really destabilize markets are speculators who can shift some of their market risk to other people or entities in ways that allow them to profit from transactions whose expected value is negative.

Comment: @JamesK: the expression bank run comes from the notion that clients ran to the bank - quite literally - when they learned it has financial problem and that their savings were at risk.

Comment: @supercat: I only partially agree. You might find the research and reporting they're doing over at http://www.deepcapture.com interesting (however sulfurous the team might be in some media spheres).

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming that the article you referred to is the first hit on Google under "Corbyn" and "run on the pound": [Jeremy Corbyn: It's right to plan for run on pound](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-41393021)

If so, I'm afraid you're not interpreting what the article said correctly.

It says:

> Jeremy Corbyn says it is "right to look at all these scenarios" after his shadow chancellor suggested that there could be a run on the pound if Labour went into government.
>   John McDonnell said Labour was doing "war-game-type scenario-planning" for events such as "a run on the pound".

Corbyn doesn't want to ***do*** a run on the pound (to be more precise, this article does not say that he wants it. Whether he wants to or not is not something I know, as I don't know how to read minds yet).

The article says that he wants to **prepare how to respond** in the eventuality that a run on the pound happens (intentionally or not) as a result of Labour party forming the government.

Comment: Actually it was a piece of rather over-enthusiastic reporting - McDonnell said that they were wargaming all kinds of scenarios, including a run on the pound. The way it was reported made it sound like a run might be a natural consequence of a Labour election, which nobody actually suggested up until that point. It would be pure conjecture based on characterisation of Labour manifesto policies as "dangerous" or "extreme" when actually they are quite normal centre-left policies which many other countries already adopted.

Comment: @jambox Which is only to be expected; the BBC are not exactly objective.

Comment: @jambox - i'm not sure, it semed to be BBC article was extremely clear what the situation was. Maybe because i specialize in finance so it kind of was the obvious explanation even before I read the article

Comment: @user4012 - your answer was definitely correct, it's just a question of framing. IOW, was it fair to report "Labout preparing for a run on the pound", or was that cherrypicking a sentence from a conference speech (which is intended to be internal to the party) and reporting it as a way of making Corbyn look bad?

Answer (score 3):

I think he's overstating expectations here. There was, immediately after Brexit, [a serious run on the British Pound](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2016/06/24/the-british-pound-has-suffered-a-stunning-collapse)

> The British pound fell more than 10 percent on Thursday night, reaching $1.34 per pound, after midnight Eastern time, a stunning decline for a rich country's currency in a single day. The plunge came as United Kingdom  voted to leave the European Union, a historic event that shatters 40 years of efforts to foster economic integration on the continent.

Inside Britain that wouldn't have a lot of immediate effect, but over time that causes a jump in prices. So let's say it cost £100 for three barrels of oil before. A 10% drop in the value of the Pound means you now have to spend £111 for those same three barrels. Remember, the seller has to convert that currency to something they can use, so someone is having to sell Pounds. This generally leads to inflation (where prices rise in a long-term way).

There's not much a government can do to stop a run (markets are global now). In fact, in 1992 the UK tried unsuccessfully to stop the events now known as [Black Wednesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Wednesday), where the Pound was being short sold by a hedge fund

> The UK government attempted to prop up the depreciating pound to avoid withdrawal from the monetary system the country had joined two years earlier. John Major raised interest rates to 10 percent and authorized the spending of billions worth of foreign currency reserves to buy up the sterling being sold on the currency markets, but the measures failed to prevent the pound falling below its minimum level in the ERM.

Corbyn seems to be talking about another run based on [a potential Labour Party victory in the next election](http://www.express.co.uk/finance/city/859307/what-is-a-run-on-the-pound-meaning-labour-john-mcdonnell-jeremy-corbyn)

> The planning scenario means a Labour victory would ultimately trigger the fall in the value of the pound, which has already fallen following the Brexit vote, and could be devastating for the UK economy.

Comment: I changed the example from a made-up £100/bbl to £100/(3 bbl).  The price of oil just before the Brexit vote was close to $ 50/bbl, and the price of the pound was about $ 1.49/£.